# GradleException Could not create ZIP

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

Caused by: `org.gradle.api.GradleException:` Could not create ZIP `'/jenkins/repository/workspace/profile/build/libs/../profile.jar'`.

```
Project
    common  << I build under this directory
    profile

build.gradle(in common)
    ...
    dependencies {
    compile project(':../profile')
    ...

settings.gradle(in common)
    include '../profile'
```

It works on windows environment. But it does not work on `linux` environment even using `root` account

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The project paths accepted by the `include` and `project` methods are *logical* paths, not physical paths. They cannot contain a `..`. Physical paths must be declared separately in `settings.gradle` (if they divert from the logical path). The easiest way to declare a flat physical directory layout is to use the `includeFlat` method:

common/settings.gradle

```
includeFlat 'profile'
```

common/build.gradle

```
dependencies {
    compile project(':profile')
}
```

You can find more information on this topic in the "multi-project builds" chapter of the [Gradle User Guide](http://gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/userguide_single.html).

Answer (score 2):

Another common issue that can happen here especially if you're using windows is you could have opened the previous jar up in 7zip or some other tool and that's causing the file to be locked. To test this try to delete the jar that's sitting in build/libs if you can't delete the file it's locked by another program more than likely. :D

Answer (score 0):

An even shorter way to fix this: Add the following line to the `build.gradle` file of the included profile project:

```
archivesBaseName = 'profile'
```

This overwrites the default name of the jar.